# Svg icon not working on desktop but work fine on mobile

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design

Hello my svg icons are not working on desktop i get only a white space but the icon work fine on mobile devices this is my code :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56" height="56" fill="none"><g clip-path="url(#a)" fill="#000"><path d="M13.079 49.653H5.137v1.682h7.942v-1.682ZM25.476 49.653h-7.942v1.682h7.942v-1.682ZM37.873 49.653H29.93v1.682h7.942v-1.682ZM50.27 49.653h-7.942v1.682h7.942v-1.682Z"></path><path d="M0 0v56h56V0H0Zm54.255 1.744v9.968H1.745V1.744h52.51Zm0 11.712v31.89H10.997l-3.346-3.4H1.745v-28.49h52.51Zm-52.51 40.8V43.69H6.92l3.347 3.4h43.989v7.164H1.744Z"></path><path d="M8.095 5.557H5.944v1.745h2.15V5.557ZM49.807 5.557h-7.35v1.745h7.35V5.557ZM17.354 39.71l1.095-1.358-9.569-7.718 8.864-7.396-1.118-1.34-10.496 8.76 11.224 9.052ZM34.54 38.371l1.142 1.319 10.483-9.08-11.236-8.73-1.07 1.377 9.557 7.425-8.877 7.69ZM30.347 16.43l-9.5 26.172 1.64.595 9.5-26.171-1.64-.596ZM5.66 45.448a.765.765 0 1 0-1.53 0 .765.765 0 0 0 1.53 0Z"></path></g><defs><clipPath id="a"><path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h56v56H0z"></path></clipPath></defs></svg>
```

and this is my [website](https://new.carre-webagency.com/) :

Comment: The snippet works fine for me on desktop Firefox.

Comment: You have multiple icons there that contain `<clipPath id="a">` - that duplication of IDs is likely the culprit here.

Comment: @CBroe yes you're right its the id problem, thanks :)